# How to remove just an html anchor tag from a node being passed as a parameter in xslt?

Tags: templates, xslt

I have a data node that is being passed as a parameter in a template call, I want to strip out any html anchor tags but keep all other formatting html tags.

XML Data

```
<td class="ou-text-2"><p>The college's brand standards for logo treatment, font usage, and <a href="url-link">color usage</a>, along with templates for PowerPoint presentations, memos, and email signatures. The downloadable <a href="http://url-link.pdf" target="_blank">Brand Standards Guide</a> is available.</p></td>
```

Template Call XSL

```
<xsl:call-template name="remove-a">
<xsl:with-param name="description" select="tbody/tr[@class = 'ou-text']/td[@class = 'ou-text-2']"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Remove Anchor Tag Template XSL

```
<xsl:template name="remove-a">
<xsl:param name="description"/> 
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$description/a">
<xsl:for-each select="$description/a/node()">
<xsl:copy-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:for-each> -->
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:copy-of select="$description"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I know the *normalize-space function* **IS NOT** what I need, but I don't know how to get what I need and that's just in there because it at least returns a value.

What I want to get

```
<p>The college's brand standards for logo treatment, font usage, and color usage, along with templates for PowerPoint presentations, memos, and email signatures. The downloadable Brand Standards Guide is available.</p>
```

What I'm getting

```
color usage Brand Standards Guide
```

Comment: Why do you think a named template is a good tool for the stated purpose?

Comment: because I may have other instances where I need to do the same thing.

Comment: I don't think that's a good reason. Why don't you post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Define a mode with the identity transformation as the base template and then add e.g. `<xsl:template match="a"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>` to handle the `a`elements.

Push any node you want to strip anchor elements from through that mode.